In Luke 14:25, is there a change in audience, ie from the home of a Pharisee (verses 1-24) to "the multitude" while traveling on the road?
Luke chapter 14 begins with Jesus addressing lawyers and Pharisees at the home of one of the chief Pharisees. The audience appears to be the same all the way down to verse 24, which is the end of a parable told by Jesus.
Then verse 25(KJV):

And there went great multitudes with him: and he turned, and said unto them...

Are we supposed to understand that the scene and related audience, changes in verse 25 from the home of the Pharisee to the multitude on the road?
In verse 25, the phrase "great multitudes with him" gives us the impression that the scene has shifted from a home to the road. So, when verse 25 states "and he turned" it appears that Jesus turns to address the multitude as they were traveling.
However, the context of the chapter does not change leading you to consider that there is no change in venue/audience. That is, the lesson of denying yourself and your own way of approaching God (including valuing your own works of morality) and taking up the cross to follow Jesus by grace/faith alone, continues throughout the entire chapter. This includes the two parables told by Jesus in verses 28-32. If there are two separate audiences, are we then to assume that Jesus intended for the entire lesson to be for the gospel reader alone and not these separate audiences at that time?
Also, please note in verse 2 the man with the dropsy. Are we to assume that this man is a "plant" in order for the Pharisees to entrap Jesus to heal on the Sabbath Day?  The point here is that if there are two separate audiences, then the man with the dropsy and "the multitude" in verse 25 are mutually exclusive and there isn't some type of courtyard in the home of the chief Pharisee where "the multitude" could be watching the entire exchange thereby being just one large audience. Hope you can follow the logic here.

The order of events appears to go like this (Verses 1-6):
Jesus is dining at the home of a leading Pharisee.
Two possibilities exist:

this scene is in an area outside the Pharisee's house, where
observers have gathered. This seems likely.
Note: Jesus went. The Greek verb "erchomai" primarily means "to come" or "to go." It is used extensively in the New Testament to describe physical movement from one place to another [1]

this scene is inside the Pharisee's house. (Perhaps in an open or semi-open courtyard where a larger social gathering could take place.)



One Sabbath, when he went to dine at the house of a ruler of the
Pharisees, they were watching him carefully. 2 And behold, there was a
man before him who had dropsy. 3 And Jesus responded to the lawyers
and Pharisees, saying, “Is it lawful to heal on the Sabbath, or not?”
4 But they remained silent. Then he took him and healed him and sent
him away. 5 And he said to them, “Which of you, having a son or an
ox that has fallen into a well on a Sabbath day, will not immediately
pull him out?” 6 And they could not reply to these things.

In verses 3-6, Jesus initiates a dialogue on the legality of healing on the Sabbath. Jesus initiates with the man with dropsy so this man is likely not a plant.
Verse 7 and 15 makes it clear that Jesus is speaking to those who had been invited. This means they are inside the Pharisee's home for the meal.

Now he told a parable to those who were invited, when he noticed how
they chose the places of honor, saying to them,


When one of those who reclined at table with him heard these things,
he said to him, “Blessed is everyone who will eat bread in the kingdom
of God!”

Change of scene (Verse 25):
"Now great crowds accompanied him, and he turned and said to them," as noted, Jesus seems to have moved from the Pharisee's home to an outdoor setting with a larger audience.

As background, we should be aware that there were different opinions among the Pharisees regarding healing on the Sabbath. All agreed that no "work" was allowed, but for many, saving a life was an exception. Here, the man's life was not at risk, but the definition of work was unsettled. Some held that mixing medicines was not allowed but since prayers for healing were not work, the kind of healing that Jesus often did was not forbidden. So we are dealing here with an issue that was contentious - not only between Jesus and other rabbis - but among the rabbis themselves. Now to the text:

1 On a sabbath he went to dine at the home of one of the leading
Pharisees, and the people there were observing him carefully. 2 In
front of him there was a man suffering from dropsy. 3 Jesus spoke to
the scholars of the law and Pharisees in reply, asking, “Is it lawful
to cure on the sabbath or not?”

This opening dialogue should be read as taking place outside his host's home, where "the people there were observing him carefully." Among them was the man with dropsy. Since Jesus' initiates the dialog, we should probably not see the man as a plant. Rather, Jesus responds to the man's plight and also takes the opportunity to open a  halakhic discussion with his fellow rabbis about healing on the Sabbath. The issue was still unsettled in Jewish tradition, and the silence of the scholars on the matter is an indication of this.
The scene then moves indoors. There is definitely a change of audience in verse 25, where the scene shifts from the Pharisee's home to somewhere else, where Jesus addresses the "great crowds."
Conclusion: The man was probably not a plant. However, since the Pharisees themselves were not of one accord on this issue, it is possible that one faction of the Pharisees might have brought him to the place in order to see whether Jesus agreed with them or their opponents. Regarding the audiences, I tend to see the incident with afflicted man as happening either in a courtyard or a public area on the way to wealthy Pharisee's home. At verse 7, Jesus addresses "those who had been invited." I read this a shift from outside to indoors at the dinner event. Then, at verse 25 we are outside again, with Jesus addressing a large crowd. This seems to be a new scene altogether and may just as well be read as a separate chapter.

Ah, I think you've got it. The KJV states that "AS He went into the house..." So it looks like all of chapter 14 takes place outside the home of one of the Pharisees. The crowds followed him to the doorstep of the Pharisees home and then Jesus paused when He saw the man with the dropsy. He then addresses the entire crowd which included the Pharisees. In verse 25, He then just turns to the crowds that followed Him to continue the lesson. So, I read this now as one continuous narrative, one venue, one audience. If you change your answer to state this, I'll select it as the final answer.

I need to do a better job of reading the full context. You make a good point about verse 7 and verse 9 supports the scene has moved inside. Still pondering the fact that the context is the same for the entire chapter.

Sorry, make that verse 15 not 9
